# Gunpoint: How To Get The Clean Record Achievement?

Tags: achievements, gunpoint

On Gunpoint, I was wondering how to get all the achievements, then I stumbled upon "Clean Record" or something like that, and the achievement isn't clear on what you need to do to get it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found this in a [Steam Community Guide](https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=150411310):

> Clean Record:
>   "Complete the police chief’s missions without incriminating yourself."
>
> Don't get caught on any cameras during Mayfield: The Room, then be sure to give him the real file as it's a fake he uploaded to try and catch you lying.

You might have a look at [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LEKaLePXmQE) too.